# [dcc32 Warning] UnloadProcs.pas(59): W1035 Return value of function 'GetType' might be undefined

Tags: сборка, delphi, delphi-7, функции

Есть тип данных

```
type
TDataTypeId = (DataTypeId_String, DataTypeId_SmallInt, DataTypeId_Integer, DataTypeId_Word,
               DataTypeId_Boolean, DataTypeId_Float, DataTypeId_Currency,
               DataTypeId_BCD, DataTypeId_FmtBCD, DataTypeId_Date,
               DataTypeId_Time, DataTypeId_DateTime, DataTypeId_TimeStamp,
               DataTypeId_Bytes, DataTypeId_VarBytes, DataTypeId_Blob,
               DataTypeId_Memo, DataTypeId_Graphic, DataTypeId_fmtMemo,
               DataTypeId_FixedChar, DataTypeId_WideChar, DataTypeId_LargeInt,
               DataTypeId_Array, DataTypeId_FixedWideChar, DataTypeId_WideMemo);
```

Есть функция, которая принимая строку, содержащую в себе одно из значений этого типа, возвращает это значение

```
Function GetType(str: string): TDataTypeId;
var
typeidx: TDataTypeId;
typestr: string;
begin
for typeidx := Low(TDataTypeID) to High(TDataTypeID) do
 begin
  typestr:=GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TDataTypeId),Ord(typeidx));
  typestr:=Copy(typestr, 12, length(typestr)-11);
  //Memo.Lines.Add(typestr+'\n');
  if (AnsiCompareStr(str, typestr)=0) then
     Result:=typeidx
 end;
 end;
```

В результате сборки возникает

```
[dcc32 Warning] UnloadProcs.pas(59): W1035 Return value of function 'GetType' might be undefined
```

Как преобразовать функцию, чтобы предупреждение не возникало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данное предупреждение говорит о том что возможна ситуация когда результат будет пустой,
чтобы убрать это предупреждение добавть в начало функции строку

```
Result:=  DataTypeId_Array;
```

то есть сделайте какой то вариант результата по умолчанию

Answer (score 0):

Зачем так сложно?

```
i := GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TDataTypeId), 'datatypeid_' + edt1.Text);
if i <> -1 then result := TDataTypeId(i)
```

Comment: Даже в вашем варианте возможен вариант когда результат будет пустой, так что инициализировать результат нужно.

Да и использовать в функциях значение компонентов не совсем кошерно.